# Merging output on mongo pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have created an aggregation with mongo that will be scheduled to run every 5 min and will add the result to an output collection. The problem is, the values are being replaced, and what I want is to sum them. This is the result document in my collection after running it for the first time:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "ID" : "ID0001",
        "NAME" : "NAME0001"
    },
    "total_a" : 8.0,
    "total_b" : 2.0,
    "total_c" : 5.0,
    "total_d" : 5.0,
    "TOTAL" : 35.0
}
```

When I run it again after 5 min, I get:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "ID" : "ID0001",
        "NAME" : "NAME0001"
    },
    "total_a" : 2.0,
    "total_b" : 3.0,
    "total_c" : 3.0,
    "total_d" : 3.0,
    "TOTAL" : 11.0
}
```

What I want is to add the values in the destination, not replacing the document. So, the result document should be:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "ID" : "ID0001",
        "NAME" : "NAME0001"
    },
    "total_a" : 10.0,
    "total_b" : 5.0,
    "total_c" : 8.0,
    "total_d" : 8.0,
    "TOTAL" : 46.0
}
```

A solution could be a $lookup stage to join and then add the values. but, is there any other way to tell Mongo to don't replace the document and just sum the values?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your current query resulting in what you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write update queries created from aggregation result and update collection.

The below code queries for `_id` and increments the  values based on the aggregation values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    aggregation code
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    var _id = doc._id; 
    var total_a = doc.total_a; 
    db.collection.update({ "_id" : _id },
      { $inc: {"total_a" : total_a } } )
};
```

You can use bulk write if you have more rows to update.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll try that.